# Haskell/Parsec: How do you use the functions in Text.Parsec.Indent?

Tags: parsing, haskell, indentation, parsec

I'm having trouble working out how to use any of the functions in the [`Text.Parsec.Indent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Indent.html) module provided by the [`indents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/indents-0.3.3) package for Haskell, which is a sort of add-on for Parsec.

What do all these functions do? How are they to be used?

I can understand the brief Haddock description of `withBlock`, and I've found examples of how to use `withBlock`, `runIndent` and the `IndentParser` type [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/03/16/using-text-parsec-indent-to-parse-an-indentation-sensitive-language-with-haskells-parsec-library/), [here](http://changaco.net/blog/parse-indented-tree/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533730/haskell-parsec-indents-please-give-an-example-for-how-to-use-each-of-the-functi). I can also understand the documentation for the four parsers [`indentBrackets` and friends](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Indent.html#g:4). But many things are still confusing me.

In particular:

1. What is the difference between `withBlock f a p` and

   ```
   do aa <- a
      pp <- block p
      return f aa pp
   ```

   Likewise, what's the difference between `withBlock' a p` and `do {a; block p}`
2. In the family of functions [`indented` and friends](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Indent.html#g:3), what is ‘the level of the reference’? That is, what is ‘the reference’?
3. Again, with the functions `indented` and friends, how are they to be used? With the exception of `withPos`, it looks like they take no arguments and are all of type `IParser ()` (IParser defined like [this](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/03/16/using-text-parsec-indent-to-parse-an-indentation-sensitive-language-with-haskells-parsec-library/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533730/haskell-parsec-indents-please-give-an-example-for-how-to-use-each-of-the-functi)) so I'm guessing that all they can do is to produce an error or not and that they should appear in a `do` block, but I can't figure out the details.

   I did at least find some examples on the usage of `withPos` in the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Indent.html), so I can probably figure that out if I stare at it for long enough.
4. [`<+/>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Indent.html#v:-60--43--47--62-) comes with the helpful description “`<+/>` is to indentation sensitive parsers what `ap` is to monads” which is great if you want to spend several sessions trying to wrap your head around `ap` and then work out how that's analogous to a parser. The other [three combinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Indent.html#g:5) are then defined with reference to `<+/>`, making the whole group unapproachable to a newcomer.

   Do I need to use these? Can I just ignore them and use `do` instead?
5. The ordinary [`lexeme`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:lexeme) combinator and [`whiteSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:whiteSpace) parser from Parsec will happily consume newlines in the middle of a multi-token construct without complaining. But in an indentation-style language, sometimes you want to stop parsing a lexical construct or throw an error if a line is broken and the next line is indented less than it should be. How do I go about doing this in Parsec?
6. In the [language](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/software/next/status/lex.html) I am trying to parse, ideally the rules for when a lexical structure is allowed to continue on to the next line should depend on what tokens appear at the end of the first line or the beginning of the subsequent line. Is there an easy way to achieve this in Parsec? (If it is difficult then it is not something which I need to concern myself with at this time.)

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? (Follow the “Source” links to the right of the type signatures in the documentation.) That should help with your first question at least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, the first hint is to take a look at `IndentParser`

```
type IndentParser s u a = ParsecT s u (State SourcePos) a
```

I.e. it's a `ParsecT` keeping an extra close watch on [`SourcePos`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Pos.html#t%3aSourcePos), an abstract container which can be used to access, among other things, the current *column* number. So, it's probably storing the current "level of indentation" in `SourcePos`. That'd be my initial guess as to what "level of reference" means.

In short, `indents` gives you a new kind of `Parsec` which is context sensitive—in particular, sensitive to the current indentation. I'll answer your questions out of order.

---

(2) The "level of reference" is the "belief" referred in the current parser context state of where this indentation level starts. To be more clear, let me give some test cases on (3).

(3) In order to start experimenting with these functions, we'll build a little test runner. It'll run the parser with a string that we give it and then unwrap the inner `State` part using an `initialPos` which we get to modify. In code

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Pos
import Text.Parsec.Indent
import Control.Monad.State

testParse :: (SourcePos -> SourcePos) 
          -> IndentParser String () a 
          -> String -> Either ParseError a
testParse f p src = fst $ flip runState (f $ initialPos "") $ runParserT p () "" src
```

(Note that this is *almost* `runIndent`, except I gave a backdoor to modify the `initialPos`.)

Now we can take a look at `indented`. By examining the source, I can tell it does two things. First, it'll `fail` if the *current* `SourcePos` column number is less-than-or-equal-to the "level of reference" stored in the `SourcePos` *stored in the `State`*. Second, it somewhat mysteriously updates the `State` `SourcePos`'s *line* counter (not column counter) to be current.

Only the first behavior is important, to my understanding. We can see the difference here.

```
>>> testParse id indented ""
Left (line 1, column 1): not indented

>>> testParse id (spaces >> indented) "   "
Right ()

>>> testParse id (many (char 'x') >> indented) "xxxx"
Right ()
```

So, in order to have `indented` succeed, we need to have consumed enough whitespace (or anything else!) to push our column position out past the "reference" column position. Otherwise, it'll fail saying "not indented". Similar behavior exists for the next three functions: `same` fails unless the current position and reference position are on the same line, `sameOrIndented` fails if the current column is strictly less than the reference column, unless they are on the same line, and `checkIndent` fails unless the current and reference columns match.

`withPos` is slightly different. It's not just a `IndentParser`, it's an `IndentParser`-combinator—it transforms the input `IndentParser` into one that thinks the "reference column" (the `SourcePos` in the `State`) is exactly where it was when we called `withPos`.

This gives us another hint, btw. It lets us know we have the power to change the reference column.

(1) So now let's take a look at how `block` and `withBlock` work using our new, lower level reference column operators. `withBlock` is implemented in terms of `block`, so we'll start with `block`.

```
-- simplified from the actual source
block p = withPos $ many1 (checkIndent >> p)
```

So, `block` resets the "reference column" to be whatever the current column is and then consumes at least 1 parses from `p` so long as each one is indented identically as this newly set "reference column". Now we can take a look at `withBlock`

```
withBlock f a p = withPos $ do
  r1 <- a
  r2 <- option [] (indented >> block p)
  return (f r1 r2)
```

So, it resets the "reference column" to the current column, parses a single `a` parse, tries to parse an `indented` `block` of `p`s, then combines the results using `f`. Your implementation is *almost* correct, except that you need to use `withPos` to choose the correct "reference column".

Then, once you have `withBlock`, `withBlock' = withBlock (\_ bs -> bs)`.

(5) So, `indented` and friends are exactly the tools to doing this: they'll cause a parse to immediately fail if it's indented incorrectly with respect to the "reference position" chosen by `withPos`.

(4) Yes, don't worry about these guys until you learn how to use [`Applicative` style](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#useful-monadic-functions) parsing in base `Parsec`. It's often a much cleaner, faster, simpler way of specifying parses. Sometimes they're even more powerful, but if you understand `Monad`s then they're almost always completely equivalent.

(6) And this is the crux. The tools mentioned so far can only do indentation failure if you can describe your intended indentation using `withPos`. Quickly, I don't think it's possible to specify `withPos` based on the success or failure of other parses... so you'll have to go another level deeper. Fortunately, the mechanism that makes `IndentParser`s work is obvious—it's just an inner `State` monad containing `SourcePos`. You can use `lift :: MonadTrans t => m a -> t m a` to manipulate this inner state and set the "reference column" however you like.

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, one more question. What's the difference between [`checkIndent` and `indented`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Indent.html#g:3)? Looking at [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/latest/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Indent.html), what's the difference between `checkIndent` and `same`?

Comment: And am I right in thinking that [`getPosition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:getPosition) gets the current position, whereas [`get`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:get) fetches the position from the last time `withPos` was called? And presumably `withPos` positions can stack/nest somehow? Oh yes, I can see from the source (of `withPos`) that they plainly do.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm being an idiot: `same` forces the item to be on the same _line_ (not column) as the reference, and `checkIndent` forces the item to be at the same _column_ as the reference. Whereas `indented` allows the item to be at the same column as or a later column than the reference.

Comment: Yeah, `SourcePos` holds both line and column counts so there's some support there for parses based on either state.